# Is there any chance to install the ubuntu touch preview on a generic tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've been trying to install the ubuntu touch preview on a generic tablet, but I still have no results. It simply won't install!

It doesnt even have the volume button, to enter the boot menu i have to do it from the android settings menu!

Thks
Oscar Gutierrez

Comment: You will probably get a better response if you list the actual type of tablet you are trying to install Ubuntu touch on instead of just saying generic tablet. Not all tablets can run Ubuntu touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will note the Supported tablets are limited to a small range (Nexus) as per this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Note that the other supported Tab lets are user supported and most support a limited set of features. It's early days so a lot of stuff will simply not work.

Answer (score -3):

For  the moment Ubuntu only can be flashed in ARMv7 and Intel

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This may answer the question, but try improving the answer by including more within the question (such as where you got the information).